# Departure time of given flight at given date

Tags: delays, flight-status

I have been looking on the internet for a solution to my problem. I had a flight delay of over 6 hours at Paris CDG, and for my complaint form I need to know the exact departure time of my flight, but I do not remember exactly.

Is there a website where I can know that?

For example: Flight AF0422 the 4th March 2014.

Thanks a lot! I hope this is the place to ask this kinds of questions, if it isn't forgive me and would be grateful for suggestions of where to find the info.

Answer (score 1):

http://flightaware.com/

They only have times a few weeks back unless you pay but March 4th is definitely still available for free

Answer (score 1):

As this is not so long ago, you can look it up on flightaware:

[AF0422](http://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/AFR422/history/20140304/0940Z/LFPG/SKBO)

For your flight that would mean that is was scheduled at 10:40 but left at 11:07.

Are you sure it was the 4th and not the 5th? Because it arrived late by 6 hours on the 5th (you can see that from the table)